# databse.php is not working in laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-5.4

I am using laravel 5.4. I have configured my config\database.php for mysql but its not inserting the records into mysql. Please see below and please give the solutions for this. why it is not inserting. when I try to insert no response.

```
<?php

return [



'default' => env('DB_CONNECTION', 'mysql'),



'connections' => [

    'sqlite' => [
        'driver' => 'sqlite',
        'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', database_path('database.sqlite')),
        'prefix' => '',
    ],

    'mongodb' => [
        'driver' => 'mongodb',
        'host' => env('DB_HOST', 'localhost'),
        'port' => 27017,
        'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'userr'),
        //'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', ''),
        //'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
    ],

    'couchdb' => array(
        'driver'   => 'couchdb',
        'type'     => 'socket',
        'host'     => 'localhost',
        'ip'       => null,
        'port'     => 5984,
        'dbname'   => 'userr',
        //'user'     => 'username',
        //'password' => 'password',
        'logging'  => false,
    ),

    'mysql' => [
        'driver' => 'mysql',
        'host' => env('DB_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
        'port' => env('DB_PORT', '3306'),
        'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'insurance'),
        'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'root'),
        'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
        'charset' => 'utf8mb4',
        'collation' => 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci',
        'prefix' => '',
        'strict' => true,
        'engine' => null,
    ],

    'pgsql' => [
        'driver' => 'pgsql',
        'host' => env('DB_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
        'port' => env('DB_PORT', '5432'),
        'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'forge'),
        'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'forge'),
        'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
        'charset' => 'utf8',
        'prefix' => '',
        'schema' => 'public',
        'sslmode' => 'prefer',
    ],

],
?>
```

here is my .env file

```
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=insurance
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=
 DB_PORT_MONGO=27017
```

my controller code

```
public function  insertlogin()
{
    //$user = DB::connection('mongodb')->collection('users')->get();
    $id = DB::table('login')->insert([
        ['username' => 'rajeshhhhh', 'password' => 'seven']
    ]);
    return $id;
}
```

If I try manual connection then it will insert. below manual connection code

```
public function  insertlogin()
{
    //$user = DB::connection('mongodb')->collection('users')->get();
    $id = DB::connection('mysql')->table('login')->insert([
        ['username' => 'rajeshhhhh', 'password' => 'seven']
    ]);
    return $id;
}
```

Comment: Where is your insertion code?

Comment: post your **insert** query and MySQL error.

Comment: I have added. Please check

Comment: If I try manual connection(DB::connection('mysql')->table('login')->insert()) then it will insert

Comment: This is not a task for a controller. You should read about [seeding](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/seeding) And maybe check out [authentication](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/authentication). If not, notice that a plain password is bad.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a Model to you table *login*, then you can use this method:

```
Login::create(['username' => 'set_your_username_here', 'password' => bcrypt('set_your_password_here')]);
```

Comment: I dont use model. I directly insert through controller. Please give solution how can I insert through controller